# iOS 11 User Custom Sound Notification

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I'm having troubles implementing the basic example code from Apple, at the following

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW3

This is my code; it's very "Textbook example". I'm currently getting an error of "'init(named:)' is unavailable"

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey:"testreminder!", arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey:"Reminder body.", arguments: nil)

    content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "test.aiff");
    content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "test.aiff", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

EDIT: Upon trying the suggestions, this is the code and it is not working. It gives a 'init(named:)' is unavailable

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey:"testreminder!", arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey:"Reminder body.", arguments: nil)

    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "test.aiff")
    content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "test.aiff", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Use the UNNotificationSoundName struct to define the sound name.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsoundname

```
let soundName = UNNotificationSoundName("test.aiff")
content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: soundName)
```

2. And make sure the **Target Membership** is checked for the sound file in the File inspector.[File inspector Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E19GP.png)

Comment: I was running into this issue as well too and I changed the audio file format to AIFF and it worked.